# Check if radiobuttonlist has certain value using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

This is probably a really silly question - but..

I have a radiobuttonlist with 2 items in it and I need to check which one of them is checked using Javascript.

What I have so far is:

```
var AspRadio = document.getElementsByName('<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>');
for (var i = 0; i < AspRadio.length; i++) {
    if (AspRadio[i].checked) {
        if (AspRadio[i].value == "item1") {
          //do stuff here
         }
        else if if (AspRadio[i].value == "item2") {
        //do stuff
         }
```

I suspect the way I am checking the radiobutton value is incorrect?!

Please help!!

Comment: my codes does not work, and i suspect that -> if (AspRadio[i].value == "item1") is not the way to check whether a radio button item is selected or not?

Comment: `else if if`, what about that part?

Comment: sorry type. but still does not work. Now i am trying: if(AspRadio[0].checked) and if(AspRadio[1].checked) but does not work as well..giving me errors...

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: '1.checked' is null or not an object

Comment: the error is for this line: else if (AspRadio[1].checked)

Answer (score 1):

With this you will be able to get the selected value of your radio button

```
var myValue = $('input[name=<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>]:checked').val();
```

**Update**

To check the selected radio you can use this

```
if ($('input:radio[name=<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>]')[0].checked)
{
}
```

Comment: hmm but I needed to check which of the two radio button is selected e.g. if

Comment: var AspRadio = document.getElementsByName('<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>');

if (AspRadio[0].checked) {
//do stuff
}
else 
if (AspRadio[1].checked) {
//do stuff
}

Comment: thanks soo  much for your help. I tried your updated code but am getting this error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Comment: thanks! really appreicated your help. stil doesn't work for me..i suspect must be some typo here or there?

Comment: I guess so. Sry I can't help you more than this

Answer (score 1):

My gosh, finally found the problem why my codes wasnt working..

Here is the solution I've got:

```
                var RB1 = document.getElementById('<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>');
                var radio = RB1.getElementsByTagName("input");

                if (radio[0].checked)
                 {
                 //do something
                 }

                if (radio[1].checked)
                {
                //do something
                 }
```

i was missing the line: var radio = RB1.getElementsByTagName("input");

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LTTBZ/).

```
function checkSelectedRadio() {

    var selectRadio = $('input[name=<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>]:checked', '#myForm').val();

    alert(selectRadio);
}
```

Comment: I basically just want to check which of the radio button items is selected. Tried to do AspRadio[0].checked and AspRadio[1].checked but does not seem to work?